# How can i underline a text in JDK5, NOT JDK6

Tags: java, swing

when i search internet i have found a way to underline font like this,

```
Font f=jLabel1.getFont();
Map<TextAttribute,Object> map = new Hashtable<TextAttribute,Object>();
map.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE,TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
f=f.deriveFont(map);
jLabel1.setFont(f);
```

it works well on jdk6, however it doesnt work on jdk5, and it doesnt warn about anything.
first, how can i get same effect on jdk5?
second, why is there a TextAttribute.UNDERLINE constant, if it doesnt work?

Comment: Looks like this bug was fixed in Java 1.6: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;:YfiG?bug_id=4296952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many bugs have been reported against the `deriveFont` methods; see [this search](http://search.sun.com/main/index.jsp?charset=utf-8&col=main-developer-bugs&qt=deriveFont&x=0&y=0&all=deriveFont&reslang=en).  I could not spot one that exactly matched your problem, but you could have better luck.  If you find a relevant bug report, there may be a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way except the somewhat ugly HTML-approach:

```
label.setText("<html>some <u>underlined</u> text</html>");
```

Beware however, that if you provide a custom look-and-feel, the HTML-rendering may no longer work as expected.

Another way would be to add a MatteBorder to the label, but that "underlines" the entire label:

```
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can work in JDK.5
   text.setText("0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    // make 0123456789 appear underlined
    `obj.underline=true` may work fine.

```
  StyleRange style1 = new StyleRange();
    style1.start = 0;
    style1.length = 10;
    style1.underline = true;
    text.setStyleRange(style1);

0123456789 is underlined.
```

Comment: What do you mean? There is no setStyleRange for a JLabel.

Comment: i dont know much about SWT, but google makes me feel that StyleRange is something SWT specific.